Sonatype Nexus database migration from H2 in EC2 to external PSQL
I currently have a Sonatype Nexus instance running on an EC2 instance with the H2 database. I'm looking to migrate the database to PostgreSQL. Sonatype Nexus offers an in-built option only for the Pro edition which unfortunately I do not own, so I'm looking to do this manually.
However, I'm unsure about the exact process to safely transfer my existing Nexus data from H2 to PostgreSQL. I've tried to extract the scripts from H2 without much success as Nexus doesn't have an option for the community edition.
If anyone ever encountered this problem, I'll be thankful if you can share what you did to attempt to solve it here.

Anyone can download the migrator utility, but it's actually the runtime use of an external PostgreSQL that is the Pro feature. You won't be able to run it once you do the migration.

The documents say postgresql and h2 database only available in pro edition.
